# How to type double acute characters using compose

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I cannot find the compose key sequence for double acute vowels like [ő](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/151/index.htm), and I need them a lot when typing in Hungarian.

I don't want to switch to a Hungarian keyboard layout as I type in Dvorak and having to switch to qwerty/qwertz every now and then would not be easy.

The keys seem to be listed [here](http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.6/doc/libX11/Compose/fi_FI.UTF-8.html), but I can't find a way to type them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On my system ő is `<compose> <=> <o>`:

```
    $ grep "Multi.*DOUBLE ACUTE" /usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose
    <Multi_key> <equal> <O>                 : "Ő"   U0150 # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER O WITH DOUBLE ACUTE
    <Multi_key> <equal> <o>                 : "ő"   U0151 # LATIN SMALL LETTER O WITH DOUBLE ACUTE
    <Multi_key> <equal> <U>                 : "Ű"   U0170 # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER U WITH DOUBLE ACUTE
    <Multi_key> <equal> <u>                 : "ű"   U0171 # LATIN SMALL LETTER U WITH DOUBLE ACUTE
    <Multi_key> <equal> <Cyrillic_U>        : "Ӳ"   U04F2 # CYRILLIC CAPITAL LETTER U WITH DOUBLE ACUTE
    <Multi_key> <equal> <Cyrillic_u>        : "ӳ"   U04F3 # CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER U WITH DOUBLE ACUTE
```

Make sure you have the basics of XCompose working before trying the more advanced ones or creating your own.

Comment: Thanks, in's working - I just didn't know how to look up the combination. Also, it turns out that `Compose`+`=`+`e` is the euro sign (€), which is also much useful, esp. in Europe.